Minimizer of forward and reverse Kullback-Leibler divergence with sum constraints on marginals
Consider minimization of the Kullback Leibler divergence between two discrete distributions $p$ and $q$:
\begin{align*}
D_{KL} \left( p \parallel q \right) = \sum_i p_i \log \left( \frac{p_i}{q_i} \right).
\end{align*}
Taken as a function of $q$, $D_{KL} \left( p \parallel q \right)$ and $D_{KL} \left( q \parallel p \right)$ have the same global minimizer: $q = p$.
Now consider a slightly different minimization problem with constraints on the marginals:
\begin{align*}
&\min_q D_{KL} \left( p \parallel q \right) = \sum_{j k} p_{j k} \log \left( \frac{p_{j k}}{q_{j k}} \right) \\
&\text{such that} \ \sum_j q_{j k} = b_k \ \text{and} \ \sum_k q_{j k} = a_j,
\end{align*}
where $a_j$ and $b_k$ are given. In this case, $D_{KL} \left( p \parallel q \right)$ and $D_{KL} \left( q \parallel p \right)$ taken as a function of $q$ no longer have the same global minimizer in general (see for example this paper, pp. 851–854, doi: 10.1068/a120843). Under which conditions, if any, can the global minimizer of $D_{KL} \left( p \parallel q \right)$ be approximated by that of $D_{KL} \left( q \parallel p \right)$, which can be computed efficiently using iterative proportional fitting (also known as RAS and biproportion)? Are there known error bounds?
